# Python - NameError: name '' is not defined

Tags: python, class, undefined, nameerror, function

I am currently expanding by python skills by programming a procedurally generated dungeon level in text format. I am confused as to why my "intersects" define is not working. Here is the class containing the def:

```
class Room:

    global x1
    global x2
    global y1
    global y2

    global w
    global h

    global centre

    def __init__(self,x,y,w,h):
        x1 = x
        x2 = x + w
        y1 = y
        y2 = y + h
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        centre = math.floor((x1 + x2) / 2),math.floor((y1 + y2) / 2)

    #function that checks if the rooms intersect by comparing corner pins relative to the x,y tile map 
    def intersects(self,room):
        if x1 <= room.x2 and x2 >= room.x1 and y1 <= room.y2 and room.y2 >=  room.y1:
            return True
        return False
```

Here is where it's called:

```
def placeRooms(r):
    rooms = []
    #Where the room data is stored

    for r in range(0,r):
        w = minRoomSize + randint(minRoomSize,maxRoomSize)
        h = minRoomSize + randint(minRoomSize,maxRoomSize)
        x = randint(1,map_width - w - 1) + 1
        y = randint(1,map_height - h - 1) + 1

        newRoom = Room(x,y,w,h)

        failed = False

        #for every room generated, this function checks if new room intersects with the last one
        for otherRoom in rooms:
            if newRoom.intersects(otherRoom):
                failed = True
                break

        if failed == False:
            createRoom(newRoom)

            rooms.append(newRoom)
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Max\Desktop\LiClipse Workspace\testing\RandomDungeon.py",      line 78, in <module>
placeRooms(2)
File "C:\Users\Max\Desktop\LiClipse Workspace\testing\RandomDungeon.py",  line  65, in placeRooms
if newRoom.intersects(otherRoom):
File "C:\Users\Max\Desktop\LiClipse Workspace\testing\RandomDungeon.py",   line 41, in intersects
if x1 <= room.x2 and x2 >= room.x1 and y1 <= room.y2 and room.y2 >= room.y1:
NameError: name 'x1' is not defined
```

I hope someone can help me understand why this code won't work, thank you.

I have managed to fix the problem. I'm sorry if my question was not defined very well. I have only been learning Python for around 4 weeks and i am used to Java which has a very different syntax. Here is my solution:

```
def __init__(self,x,y,w,h):
    self.x1 = x
    self.x2 = x + w
    self.y1 = y
    self.y2 = y + h
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.w = w
    self.h = h
```

Comment: Can you please include the full traceback in your post?

Comment: What do you *want* (or expect) all your `global` definitions to do?

Comment: Also, this should really be cut down to a MCVE. Surely the issue can be reproduced with less code.

Comment: You should consider any instance of the keyword `global` to be a bug in your code.

Comment: You keep using that [`global` keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement), I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: I included a full traceback. @MorganThrapp

Comment: your variables are not passed to the procedure, iow they are out of scope, ergo "undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As most previous comments have said, you use global variables that shouldn't be global at all.

The way I understand your code, you meant for `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y2` to be attributes of your `Room` instance, meaning that each room has its own values for `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y2`. In Python you don't have to declare attributes at the beginning of the class (where you declare all the global variables), you simply need to initialize the attributes in the `__init__` method.

This means that you can safely delete all the `global` lines, and change your `__init__` to

```
def __init__(self,x,y,w,h):
    self.x1 = x
    self.x2 = x + w
    self.y1 = y
    self.y2 = y + h
    self.w = w
    self.h = h
    centre = (self.x1 + self.x2) // 2,(self.y1 + self.y2) // 2
```

(note that you don't need `math.floor` since you're already dealing with integers, simply use the integer division operator `//`)

That way you define `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`, `w`, `h` and `center` as attributes of your class meaning that each instance has its own values for these variables. In Python, you need to add `self.` before all calls to attributes of the object itself, so you should also modify `intersects` to add `self.` before each access to an attribute of your current object (all the `x1`, `x2`, etc. that are not already prefixed by `room.` in your code).

Also, while we're at it I don't think your `intersect` function works as intended, but that's another problem :)